# How many trees are there on 7 vertices, where vertices 2 and 3 have degree 3, 5 has degree 2, and all others have degree 1?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, inclusion-exclusion

How many trees are there on 7 vertices, where vertices 2 and 3 have degree 3, 5 has degree 2, and all others have degree 1?

So far, I am able to determine that vertices 1, 4, 6, and 7 are leaves. My intuition also tells me this problem involves inclusion/exclusion somehow, but I can't quite figure out what values to calculate.

Comment: I think that should be $(n-2) \choose (deg(v_1)-1,\cdots,deg(v_n)-1)$ = $\frac{120}{4} = 30$

Comment: Nice @M.M thats smart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've figured out the solution:

The four vertices of degree 1 are leaves.

This implies that vertices 2, 3, and 5 must be adjacent.

There are three distinct ways to connect vertices 2, 3, and 5.

$$ 2 \to 3 \to 5$$
$$ 3 \to 5 \to 2$$
$$ 5 \to 2 \to 3$$

In the first case we must connect two leaves to vertex 2, one leaf to vertex 3, and one to vertex 5. This gives (4 choose 2)*(2 choose 1)*(1 choose 1) = **12 trees.**

In the second case we must connect two leaves to vertices 2 and 3. This gives (4 choose 2)*(2 choose 2) = **6 trees.**

The third case is essentially equivalent to the first, where there are **12 trees.**

In total, **$12+6+12=30$ trees can be formed** with the given specifications.

Let me know if my logic is sound.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the tree to be connected the root has to be either vertex $2$, $3$ or $5$. Starting from that point we can now pretty easily enumerate all graphs based on those roots since the tree with root degree $2$ must have either vertices $2$ and $3$ as direct children, and the rest of vertices as leaves, or it must have $2$ or $3$ as one child and a leaf as the other. Continuing in this fashion you can enumerate all trees by hand. I hope someone comes up with a better way :).